# VB.NET - Multiple Result Sets in one query?

Tags: sql, vb.net, datareader

I have a stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [TestProc]
AS
BEGIN
   select '1a', '1b'
   select '2a', '2b', '2c'
   select '3a', '3b'
END
```

If I execute the following query using SQL Management Studio,

```
exec TestProc
```

I get 3 result sets:

```
1. | 1a | 1b |

2. | 2a | 2b | 2c |

3. | 3a | 3b |
```

But when I use the stored procedure in ASP.NET(VB.NET),

```
Dim Connection As New SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("ConnToHilmarc").ToString)
Dim Command As New SqlCommand("exec TestProc @First, @Second", Connection)
Dim Reader As SqlDataReader

Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@First", "Hello")
Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Second", "World")

Connection.Open()
Reader = Command.ExecuteReader

While Reader.Read
    Response.Write(Reader(0) & " " & Reader(1) & "<br/>")
End While

Reader.Close()
Connection.Close()
```

I get only the first result set:

```
| 1a | 1b |
```

How can I get the three result sets using `SqlDataReader`? Or even three `SqlDataReader`'s? Or is it possible to get multiple result sets in just one query in VB.NET? Is `DataSet` my only option? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You'll want to use the `NextResult()` of `SqlDataReader` to get the next result set:

```
Reader.NextResult();
```

`SqlDataReader.NextResult()` returns true if there's another result set, false otherwise, so you could (in your example code), use the following loop to avoid having 3 sets of code doing essentially the same thing:

```
Using Connection As New SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("ConnToHilmarc").ToString())

    Dim Command As New SqlCommand("exec TestProc @First, @Second", Connection)
    Dim Reader As SqlDataReader

    Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@First", "Hello")
    Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Second", "World")

    Connection.Open()
    Reader = Command.ExecuteReader()

    While Reader.Read() OrElse (Reader.NextResult() And Reader.Read())
        For i As Integer = 0 To Reader.FieldCount - 1
            Response.Write(Reader(i).ToString()
            Response.Write(" ")
        Next

        Response.Write("<br />")
    End While

    Reader.Close()

End Using
```

The `OrElse` will perform logical short-circuting:

1. If Reader.Read() returns true, it will read the next row without making a call to Reader.NextResult() (which would advance the reader to the next result and possibly cause loss of data).  The `And Reader.Read()` is there to make sure you get the first row of the next result set.
2. If Reader.Read() is false, the next expression (Reader.NextResult()) will be evaluated - if it's true, it'll process the next result set.
3. If both are false, the loop is exited.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the [SqlDataReader.NextResult](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.nextresult.aspx) method.  Call it on your SqlDataReader.